# List global Windows keyboard shortcuts, all apps

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

After migrating to a new Dell from an old HP, without adding any new software packages, and doing a clean manual install of *everything*, I notice that globally the keyboard combo <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> is being grabbed by something (this makes [send] and [save] in many apps unusable, requiring a mouse move ... ich).

Looking at old posts, there are some terrible and outdated utilities that used to list all global keyboard grabs. But none worked well and some looked plain dangerous.

Is there a clean and blessed way of dumping a list of
(a) what key combos are being grabbed and,
(b) by what app or subsystem?

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but for me Save has always been CTRL+S, not ALT.

Comment: In apps, like Office, [alt][s] is used for [send] for emails. 

Interestingly, with my current predicament, you see the 'S' underlined in the "send" button, but typing [alt][s] fails to send but does display the menu shortcuts as if I had only pressed [alt].

Comment: I can not specifically answer your question but I can tell you that whatever it is that is grabbing the keyboard is something running in your startup.  Use trial and error to figure out what that might be.  90% of the crap in startup put there from Dell (or HP) are unneeded programs anyways.

Comment: Ctrl+Enter also works for send.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I have been relying on [ctrl][enter] post transition (though deprogramming my brain after decades of repetition is taking time). But other functions, such as [save] are still requiring mouse moves.